# Background at the end

Tags: android, eclipse, background

When I have an application filled with text, when I scroll down to see the end of the text, it must show me a background at the end .. I wrote this but it shows the background in the middle - I think

```
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bglow"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

How can I put a background at the end?

Edited

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bglow"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
    android:gravity="bottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textStyle="italic" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="7sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/logoline" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="5sp" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:weightSum="100" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="60"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/2" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/h"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="40"
                            android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="H"
                            android:textColor="#AD9C64"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic"
                            android:typeface="serif" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:weightSum="100" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="60"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/3" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/r"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="40"
                            android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="R"
                            android:textColor="#AD9C64"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic"
                            android:typeface="serif" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:weightSum="100" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="60"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/4" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/4"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="40"
                            android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="D"
                            android:textColor="#AD9C64"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic"
                            android:typeface="serif" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="7sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="About"
                    android:textColor="#AD9C64"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="7sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you are asking didn't get please explain more with images so can get easily

Comment: An example: http://oi62.tinypic.com/x29qon.jpg .. I'm trying to set the background at the end so when I scroll down, the background shows at the end as in "A" .. but the problem is it shows me the background always and not moving as in "B"

Comment: ok than put your full XML code for this activity

Comment: and one more question your boll always bottom of your scrollView right ? it should not scroll with other TEXT

Comment: I want it to be on the bottom, but it's not .. I added the full code

Comment: Maybe with background-position: bottom it will work but it gives me an error